# How do I get a Chansey lvl 5 with Defense Curl in GSC?

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I want to beat the Little Cup in Pokémon Stadium 2 and want a Chansey with Defense Curl for it.

But this move is learned at level 41 (GSC) or similar high in RBY.

If I breed it with a Ditto, will it get Defense Curl as long as its parent has it?

From what I read only male Pokémon can pass a move down, or if both parents have the move.

So how can I get a lvl 5 Chansey with Defense Curl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To breed a level-up move, both parents have to know the move. This means you can't breed with Ditto, but have to use a male Pokémon from [the same egg group](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Fairy_(Egg_Group)) that knows it.

However, Defense Curl is [TM40](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/TM40) in GSC, so you don't need to breed for it at all if you're willing to spend the TM (or use one of the various item creation/duplication glitches). And unlike level-up moves, TM moves can be inherited if only the father knows it, though that will still require a male from the same egg group with the move.

Answer (score 2):

Oh my bad, I didn't thought of looking at Chansey's egggroup.

A male Jigglypuff learns defense curl at level 19 in RBY.

Mated with Chansey should net a Chansey with defense curl at level 5!